# How can I show one same Vue component in two different sub route?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-router

```
const routes = [
{
    path: '/',
    component: LogInView
},
{
    path: '/store',
    component: Dashboard,
    children: [
        {
            path: '/products',
            component: ProductsView,
        },
    ]
},
{
    path: '/platform',
    component: Dashboard,
    children: [
        {
            path: '/products',
            component: ProductsView,
        },
    ]
},
{
    path: '/platform',
    component: Dashboard
} ]
```

Suppose, I am trying to render `Dashboard` component for `/store` & `/platform`,
and `ProductView` component for `/store/products` & `/platform/products` these two route.
 But the problem is when I'm hitting `/store/products` or `/platform/products` url it's rendering `Dashboard` component.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you write a slash before each child route ('/products') remove it

Answer (score 0):

In your codes, you still have a `component` on the route with the `children`:

```js
{
    path: '/store',
    component: Dashboard,
    children: [
        {
            path: '/products',
            component: ProductsView,
        },
    ]
},
```

However, the [Vuejs documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html) shows that there shouldn't be a component in the parent route, like this:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User,
      children: [
        {
          // UserProfile will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
          // when /user/:id/profile is matched
          path: 'profile',
          component: UserProfile
        },
        {
          // UserPosts will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
          // when /user/:id/posts is matched
          path: 'posts',
          component: UserPosts
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

So, instead, you should have:

```js
const routes = [
{
    path: '/',
    component: LogInView
},
{
    path: '/store',
    // component: Dashboard, // <-- should be removed
    children: [
        {
            path: 'products',
            component: ProductsView,
        },
    ]
},
{
    path: '/platform',
    children: [
        {
            path: 'products',
            component: ProductsView,
        },
    ]
},
{
    path: '/platform',
    component: Dashboard
} ]
```

**@TEFO** was right to point out that the child route should NOT contain a slash